# SQL CE Insert Query works only outside of C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I am trying to insert a row in my User table (SQL Server Compact 3.5). This is my query (LastName, FirstName and UserPassword are NVARCHAR, IsActive is BIT):

```
INSERT INTO Users (LastName, FirstName, IsActive, UserPassword) VALUES ('J', 'R', 1, 'T')
```

I converted this to the following code block in C#:

```
string returnQuery = "INSERT INTO Users (LastName, FirstName, IsActive, UserPassword)"
                                   + "VALUES(" + "'" + "@LastName" + "', '" + "@FirstName" + "', @IsActive" + ",'" + "@UserPassword" + "'";

        SqlCeCommand returnQueryCommand =
            new SqlCeCommand(returnQuery, connection) { CommandType = CommandType.Text };
        returnQueryCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", newUser.LastName);
        returnQueryCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", newUser.FirstName);
        returnQueryCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsActive", newUser.IsActive);
        returnQueryCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserPassword", newUser.UserPassword);
```

I get a parsing error when running my code. However, when I run the query straight through CompactView, the row gets inserted just fine.

I am executed the query in another method (I am returning SqlCeCommand from this method).

Thoughts?

Comment: It's just `INSERT INTO Users (LastName, FirstName, IsActive, UserPassword) VALUES (@LastName, @FirstName, @IsActive, @UserPassword)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

missing close bracket after values

Comment: Duh! I'm such a doof. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your given code seems to be missing a closing parenthesis to close "VALUES" data.

```
string returnQuery = "INSERT INTO Users (LastName, FirstName, IsActive, UserPassword)" + "VALUES(" + "'" + "@LastName" + "', '" + "@FirstName" + "', @IsActive" + ",'" + "@UserPassword" + "')";
```